# How to decode the file uploaded in postman using python starlette

Tags: python, postman, starlette

I have uploaded a .mp4 file in postman and now i need to read the file contents into a variable in python
This is my postman upload
[image]

This is my python file where i my request will be catched in this function
now how will be decode the file uploaded in this function

```
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.routing import Route, Mount
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import PlainTextResponse, FileResponse   

class Post:
    async def PostValuesToDb(requests: Request):
        return PlainTextResponse("true")


routes = [
    Route("/post", Post.PostValuesToDb,
          name="PostValuesToDb", methods=["POST"]),

]

app = Starlette(
    routes=routes
)
```

PostValuesToDb(requests: Request) captures the postman request.

Answer (score 0):

as per the [documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#request-files)

for the time being i am choosing to save the contents in a local directory, you can do as you wish from the contents variable

```
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.routing import Route, Mount
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.responses import PlainTextResponse, FileResponse   

class Post:
    async def PostValuesToDb(requests: Request):
        form = await requests.form()
        # print(dir(form)) # check what methods and attrs are available
        # print(form.multi_items) # check all form fields submitted
        filename = form["image"].filename # my particular form field
        contents = await form["image"].read()
        with open(f'./data/{filename}', 'wb') as uploaded_file:
            uploaded_file.write(contents)
        return PlainTextResponse("true")


routes = [
    Route("/post", Post.PostValuesToDb,
          name="PostValuesToDb", methods=["POST"]),

]

app = Starlette(
    routes=routes
)
```